# Can a numerical optimization algorithm get stuck into local maxima?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I've designed a cost function of the form

$$
c(x) = \sum_j f_j(x) + \lambda \sum_j g_j(x)
$$

which I'm trying to minimize (it's more specifically a non linear least square problem). When I run my algorithm (which is provided by a Matlab toolbox) the final result essentially  seems to get stuck in some "local maxima" (when $\lambda$ is high).

More specifically my setup was a relatively high $\lambda$. and some configurations of the $x$ maximize some $f_j$.

I know in general algorithms can get stuck in local minima when minimizing, but I'm surprised an optimization problem can get stuck in local maxima.

Again, is this something that can happen?

Comment: It's not necessarily a red flag if the result maximizes some $f_j$. Is the computed result a local maximum of the actual objective $c$?

Comment: Yep, it is. But still it's just an odd situations, and I was wondering if this is something that can happen.

Comment: @user8469759 if you have a particularly flat local maxima, then depending on convergence conditions that are defined i.e change between steps, then you could. But I agree that I have not really experienced this. 

How are you testing? you have plotted the function you want to maximise?

Comment: It's algorithm to process a triangular mesh. So I'm plotting the result and I've noticed some configurations are totally opposite. For each triangle I have an $f_j$ and that configuration maximize the $f_j$, literally I have compute the partial derivative and that is $0$ for those triangles. I mean overall is a local minima, but for those $f_j$ they're a local maxima. The algorithm used is a quasi-newton scheme, though I think I'll switch to Levenberg-Marquadt later.

Comment: If the solution is a local minimum of the overall objective, that is definitely something that can happen. For example let $f(x)=x^4-x^2$ and $g(x)=10x^2$.